# Wordpress linking to password protected content

Tags: security, wordpress

I just redid my company's Joomla website to work on the WP platform.  My problem is that there is content that log-in is required to access.  In our newsletter, I need to link to content that requires log-in.  Currently, If I link to that content and the customer is not logged-in, they get a 404 error.  Putting the content to be openly accessed is not an option.

Is there a plugin or some way for this to occur:

Link on newsletter to specific content --> log-in with credentials --> redirected to the specific content

I would very much appreciate your help with this!!!

Answer (score 0):

In the post/page editing form at the admin page, there is a "Visibility" option on the "Publish" field. Just check the password protected, and you can hide the page/post with the password.

hope it help..